Is there a way to capture name of group for a `group_by` in polars?
Is there a way to get the name of a current group for any given iteration of a group_by instance without having to rely to the GroupBy.__iter__()?
pl.Config().set_fmt_str_lengths(100)
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'fruit':['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'pear'],
    'origin':['mountain', 'valley', 'beach', 'beach'],
    'color':['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'green']
    
})

def udf(df_group, something="arg def"):
    something = something + " gets modified in the udf"
    return df_group.with_columns(pl.lit(something).alias('from_udf'))


print(df.group_by('origin').map_groups(udf))

shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬──────────┬────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ fruit ┆ origin   ┆ color  ┆ from_udf                         │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---                              │
│ str   ┆ str      ┆ str    ┆ str                              │
╞═══════╪══════════╪════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ pear  ┆ valley   ┆ green  ┆ arg def gets modified in the udf │
│ apple ┆ mountain ┆ red    ┆ arg def gets modified in the udf │
│ peach ┆ beach    ┆ yellow ┆ arg def gets modified in the udf │
│ pear  ┆ beach    ┆ green  ┆ arg def gets modified in the udf │
└───────┴──────────┴────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘


# Desired functionality
print(df.group_by('origin').map_groups(udf, something=__name_of_group__))

shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬──────────┬────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ fruit ┆ origin   ┆ color  ┆ from_udf                         │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---                              │
│ str   ┆ str      ┆ str    ┆ str                              │
╞═══════╪══════════╪════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│ pear  ┆ valley   ┆ green  ┆ valley gets modified in the udf  │
│ apple ┆ mountain ┆ red    ┆ mountain gets modified in the udf│
│ peach ┆ beach    ┆ yellow ┆ beach gets modified in the udf   │
│ pear  ┆ beach    ┆ green  ┆ beach gets modified in the udf   │
└───────┴──────────┴────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘

The functionality can be achieved by manually iterating through the .group_by() object but my intuition tells me that's a no-no for performance since the iteration is delegated to python instead of polars. In an attempt to prove it here a (hopefully) valid benchmark.
Native calling using default argument.
%%timeit
df.group_by('origin').map_groups(udf)
308 µs ± 19.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Manual iteration with default argument.
%%timeit 
pl.concat([ udf(data) for name, data in df.group_by(['origin'])])
473 µs ± 43.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

Manual iteration with passed argument.
%%timeit 
pl.concat([ udf(data, something=name[0])for name, data in df.group_by(['origin'])])
486 µs ± 33.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

The origin of this question is a more complicated problem in which I've written a polars plugin that optionally generates some QC reports on disk and having the name of the group is needed for differentiating the reports of each group.
# real application example (out of context)
(
   df
   .group_by('umi').agg(
              rogtk.assemble_contig( # my plugin function
                expr=pl.col("r2_seq"),
                k=20,
                min_coverage=20,
                export_graphs=True,
                prefix=??? # here is where I would like to pass an argument based on the group's definition

  ))
)



register_plugin_function() has a pass_name_to_apply param - which sounds like what you may be really asking for.

Thanks for the pointer. I was unable to find any examples on how is the name of the series passed to the function. Also, how would it work for case where the name of another field is desired and not the one passed to the function?

So, basically you want to process each group individually with a custom function. your udf also needs to know the group name. But you can dynamically inject the group name into each group before applying the udf. Here is how oyu could do this:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'fruit': ['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'pear'],
    'origin': ['mountain', 'valley', 'beach', 'beach'],
    'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'green']
})

def udf(df_group, group_name):
    return df_group.with_columns(pl.lit(group_name + " gets modified in the udf").alias('from_udf'))

result = (
    df
    .group_by('origin')
    .map_groups(lambda group: udf(group, group['origin'][0]))
)

print(result)


which gives
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ fruit ┆ origin   ┆ color  ┆ from_udf                        │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---                             │
│ str   ┆ str      ┆ str    ┆ str                             │
╞═══════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ peach ┆ beach    ┆ yellow ┆ beach gets modified in the udf  │
│ pear  ┆ beach    ┆ green  ┆ beach gets modified in the udf  │
│ apple ┆ mountain ┆ red    ┆ mountain gets modified in the … │
│ pear  ┆ valley   ┆ green  ┆ valley gets modified in the ud… │
└───────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

BUT, and there is a but: it is not a native Polars feature. My solution is a pythonic workaround to achieve the goal using polars' existing API.
